# inheritance for @Categories Junit 4.11

Tags: java, junit4, junit-runner

I'd like to know if there is any way to gather a set of test classes together  and to run one category of tests that is common for for those tests. I'll try to explain on an example:

**I have those 2 Categories:**

```
public interface Slowtests{}
public interface Fasttests{}
```

**And the following classes and methods:**

```
@Category({SLowTests.class, FastTests.class})
Class A extends TstBase {

    @Category({SLowTests.class})
    void a1() {}

    @Category({FastTests.class})
    void a2() {}

    @Category({SLowTests.class, FastTests.class})
    void a3() {}
}

@Category({SLowTests.class, FastTests.class})
Class B extends TstBase {

    @Category({SLowTests.class})
    void b1() {}

    void b2() {}
}

@Category({SLowTests.class, FastTests.class})
Class C extends TstBase{
    void c1() {}
    void c2() {}
}
```

Now let's say I'd like to run all *Fast Tests* classes from `A` and `B` and `C` under same Test Suite and to run only the tests annotationed with `FastTests` category.

Hope my question is clear enough.
Please advise what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Define your test suite like this:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(FastTests.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( /* Your test classes here */)
public class FastTestSuite {
}
```

Here's [the official documentation and example](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories).

Comment: Thank you.
Is there any chance that class A and B would inherit from lets say Class D that would extend TstBase and A and B will extend D instead of TstBase?
Or  to run a whole Package of TestClasses instead of writing each class in the SuiteClasses?